# Only last element of array being used when replacing text

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-replace

I am trying to replace some "common" words from a large block of text, however it's only using the last word from the array, please can you see where I'm going wrong?
Thanks

```
$glue = strtolower ($glue);//make all lower case
//remove common words
$Maffwordlist = array('the','to','for');
foreach($Maffwordlist as $Maffword)
$filtered = preg_replace("/\s". $Maffword ."\s/", " ", $glue);
```

The extract above only removes 'for' from the text, 'the' and 'to' are still included.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the subject of your `preg_replace()` is always `$glue`, which itself never changes.  Before iterating your list of words, you need to assign the starting contents of `$glue` into `$filtered` since that is what you are acting on in order to accumulate all the values into it.

```
// $filtered is the string you'll be modifying...
$filtered = strtolower ($glue);//make all lower case
$Maffwordlist = array('the','to','for');

foreach($Maffwordlist as $Maffword) {
   $filtered = preg_replace("/\s". $Maffword ."\s/", " ", $glue);
}
```

#### But we can do better.

A regular expression can be constructed to handle all the replacements without a loop using a `(a|b|c)` grouping.

```
// Stick the words together with pipes
$pattern = implode("|", $Maffwordlist);
// And surround with regex delimiters and ()
// so the whole regex looks like /\s(the|to|for)\s/
$pattern = '/\s(' . $pattern . ')\s/';
// And do the operation in one go:
$filtered = preg_replace($pattern, " ", $filtered);
```

I'll note you may wish to use `\b` word boundaries instead of `\s` delimiting these by whitespace. That way, you would get proper replacements in a sentence like "**You should not end a sentence with for.**" where one of your list words appears but not bound by whitespace.

Finally then, you'll end up with multiple consecutive spaces in some places where replacements have taken place.  You can collapse those into single spaces with something like the following.

```
// Replace multiple spaces  with a single space
$filtered = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $filtered);
```